# Why won't my visited link have a background color?

Tags: css, background-color

It seems that a:visited won't work in showing background color on my links.

http://jsfiddle.net/davestein/D2srA/

What super simple thing am I missing?

Comment: interesting. The border won't work either

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The background-color on `a:visited` only seems to work (as Dave said above, in FF, Chrome and Safari) if the normal `a` has a background-color, either explicitly defined or through inherit (the direct parent must actually have a background-color for this to be true).

Obviously it is not ideal to have to define a background-color for `a` all the time, as the site may have a background image.

CSS bug..?

Comment: found this old unanswered question. It's not a CSS bug, but close enough if you think of just CSS. I think it was a browser security issue so the JS couldn't rip off visited link colors as easily to track where users went.

Answer (score 3):

try a) setting a default background color (like #fff) and b)removing !important, as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/D2srA/10/

Comment: We were just noticing that as you commented - wondered how my revision got to 12. http://jsfiddle.net/davestein/D2srA/12/ Do you have any idea why it behaves this way?

Comment: The winning answer is this: http://jsfiddle.net/davestein/D2srA/31/ Using inherit gets around the quirk of transparent not being overwritten. How do we get joint points for a team effort on answer? :)

Comment: Crap, inherit doesn't work - it was working since the fiddle has a background color of white. Why god why, do I need to define some arbitrary color?

Comment: is white not okay? what about transparent?

Comment: Transparent is where I started and it doesn't work. It's not working in FF, Chrome, or Safari. It works in Opera and IE. What a backwards world we live in.

Comment: This fiddle shows why that solution is no good: http://jsfiddle.net/davestein/ALu8j/

Comment: @Dave but that's the definition of visited - it's about the site it points to, not the actual link. So naturally both links will take on the visited style.

Comment: Exactly my catch-22. It would be ideal for transparent to work since a user may have a background image on this page, that would then be blotted out by any links. Having trouble thinking of any workaround for this.

Comment: you could use JS (jQuery to make life easier) to change the bg color when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of the technical reason here, but this only seems to work for me if I add a background-color for a:

a {
background-color: #ffffff;
}

a:visited {
background-color: #ff0000;
}

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work for me if I do it like you do. But if I add every pseudo-class it works. E.g.:

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF; background-color:black;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Answer (score 0):

!important always does the truck

```
a:active {color:#0000FF !important;}
a:visited {color:#0000FF !important;}
```